# Can I use VBA to change the colour of all graphs at once?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to write a code to change all the graphs on the sheet to a specific colour but I keep running into an error

```
Sub ChangeChartColour()

Dim cht As Chart, ChtObj As ChartObject, wks As Worksheet

For Each ChtObj In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
    Set cht = ChtObj.Chart


    'ChtObj.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select

    With ChtObj.FullSeriesCollection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 1, 16)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    With ChtObj.FullSeriesCollection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 1, 16)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Next ChtObj
End Sub
```

I think that I shouldn't be using "FullSeriesCollection" but I'm not sure what to use.

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks!

CMike

Comment: "I keep running into an error" - rule of thumb, it's generally a pretty good idea to follow that statement with what the actual error is, and what specific instruction is throwing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess at what you are trying to do:

- You need `With cht` - a `FullSeriesCollection` represents all the `Series` in the *`Chart`*, not the `ChartObject`.
- You need to index into the `FullSeriesCollection` to work on a specific `Series`; I'm guessing the first.

---

```
Sub ChangeChartColour()

    Dim cht As Chart, ChtObj As ChartObject

    For Each ChtObj In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
        Set cht = ChtObj.Chart

        With cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 1, 16)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
        With cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 1, 16)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With

    Next ChtObj

End Sub
```